# Calling Java functions from R using RProtoBuf (Protocol Buffers)

Tags: java, r, rpc, protocol-buffers

It is not entirely obvious how to go about using RProtoBuf for communicating between R and other languages (Java, in my case).

The RprotoBuf Developers developed something that is still here - https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/java/?root=rprotobuf, but it seems very outdated. I am not sure if this is the way to go. Here are two conversations between the authors of RProtoBuf that might help with understanding the code -

http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rprotobuf-yada/2009-December/000116.html

http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rprotobuf-yada/2009-December/000119.html

It seems that they started work with Java and then abandoned it in C++'s favour!

Is there anyone using R-RProtoBuf-Java combination? How do you do it? Is there a tutorial or example available?

My exposure to Java is very very limited. I want to use a few programs written in Java.

Edit :
To clarify, I suppose I want to see an example of an R rpc client being used with RProtobuf. Pointers towards Java RPC servers would be welcome.

Edit2 :
The first link actually points to some documentation generator code, as Dirk pointed out.

Comment: As a side point; protobuf itself doesn't define any specific RPC details (only the serialization format) - so if you are talking RPC, you must also see what RPC is available for the "other end" (or do something simple yourself)

Comment: No, the Java directory was just meant for a documentation generator.  And protobuf is *language-agnostic* but Java is supported by a  Google implementation.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I read the conversation and then assumed the folder must have had the code. So is that code available anywhere? I would really like to see an example/ tutorail/ walk-through somewhere. And does R have an RPC client? cran didn't reveal any.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about RProtoBuf, but if you just want to call Java from R, then you might be interested in [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/).

It is not outdated and has examples (right on the main page, see the link).

Comment: I have been told that with rJava, I have to get my hands dirty with more details than I want (i.e., that it is low level.) I am looking around for all possible solutions before I invest myself in one of them.

Comment: @Soumendra That sounds reasonable. Actually I don't know how difficult it is to call Java from R. I only used rJava (JRI) to call R from Java so far. JRI is low level, but straightforward I would say.

Answer (score 1):

We have recently published a preprint on arXiv of a JSS paper we wrote with more examples of using RProtoBuf, including sending RPC requests to remote web services.  For more exposition of sharing data between R and other languages with RProtoBuf, see [RProtoBuf: Efficient Cross-Language Data Serialization in R](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7372).

You can use RProtoBuf with any transport mechanism, as explained in the article -- You can save serialized protocol buffers to files to be read by other applications written in other languages, or you can send them over connections/sockets or other higher level RPC systems.  Protocol Buffers are widely used in everything from Sony Playstations to large scale web services, but they do not include an RPC system -- you use them as your serialization format with whatever transport system you are already using.